# How to return the smallest integers from array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, methods

I have an array int[] a= {5,3,1,2} and I want to make a method that picks out the "k" smallest numbers and return an array with the k smallest integers in ascending order. But when I run this code I get the output: [1,3].
I know the code skips some numbers somehow, but I cant twist my brain to fix it.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Without sorting the original array.

```
 public static int[] nrSmallest(int[] a, int k)  {
            if(k <1 || k>a.length)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("must be at least 1");
            int[] values= Arrays.copyOf(a, k);
            Arrays.sort(values);
            int counter= 0;  
                for(int i= k; i < a.length; i++)    {
                        if(a[i]< values[counter])   {
                            for(int j= k-1; j> counter; j--)    {
                                values[j]= values[j-1];
                            }
                                values[counter]= a[i];  
                        }
                        if(counter< k) counter++;
                }
            return values;
        }
```

EDIT: Joop Eggen solved this for me. Scroll down to see answer. Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Why don't you simply sort the array, and return the `k - 1` element?

Comment: I think an easier approach would be to sort the entire array, and then return array[0..k-1].

Comment: OP is probably learning algorithm design, and probably looking for something better than O(n*logn).

Comment: Hi! Yes, Im studying algorithms. And you are not allowed to sort the original array. You have to make an array with length "k" as I have done above

Comment: @pamphlet Hi! No I haven't used a debugger on it. I dont think my debugger works properly. :p

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan Learning an IDE/debugger can be a steep learning curve, but well worth the investment. And inevitable if this is a career path for you. (Not very helpful with your immediate issue, I realize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(Corrected)*** To keep your code:

```
            for (int i= k; i < a.length; i++) {
                    if (a[i] < values[counter]) { // Found small value
                        // Insert sorted
                        for (int j = k-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                            if (j == 0 || a[i] > values[j-1]) { // Insert pos
                                // Move greater ones up.
                                for (int m = k - 1; m > j; m--) {
                                    values[m] = values[m - 1];
                                }
                                values[j] = a[i]; // Store
                                break; // Done
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: looked plausible :) , but when I tried it wit an array of {5,3,1,2} it returned [3,5]

Comment: it returned [3,5] if I used System.out.println(nrSmallest(a,2));

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan corrected, `for-j` did not visit all insert positions.

Comment: This is great, something similiar that I'm trying to do. But sadly, your method still gives wrong answers. If the array is a= {5,3,1,9,2,7} and you try to print out nrSmallest(a,2) you get [1,2,3,3]. It should have returned [1,2,3,5]

Comment: The `for-m` to shift the elements was in the wrong order, copying instead of shifting. _Not so great. But I am concentrated on other things._

Comment: Thanks! That really did it! 
I had tried to solve it for so long now that I couldn't concentrate. Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out in the comments, simply return a part of the sorted array.

```
public static int[] nrSmallest(int[] a, int k)  {
    // check parameters..

    // copy all so we don't sort a
    int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);
    return Arrays.copyOf(sorted, Math.min(k, sorted.length));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify the original array, this is typically done with some type of priority queue, often a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

The method that you use in your example is O(n^2), and uses O(k) extra space. Sorting the original array and selecting the top k items is O(n log n). If you copy the array and then sort it, it uses O(n) extra space.

Using a heap is O(n log k), and requires O(k) extra space.

There is an O(n) solution that involves manipulating the original array (or making a copy of the array and manipulating it). See [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

My own testing shows that Quickselect is faster in the general case, but Heap select is faster when the number of items to be selected (k) is less than 1% of the total items (n). See my blog post, [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/). That comes in quite handy when selecting, say, the top 100 items from a list of two million.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

int[] values= Arrays.copyOf(a, k); this line is wrong. you are copying only k elements. but you are suppose to copy all elements and then sort the array.

Comment: Hi! Yeah, i know. Thats how we (students) are supposed to do it. Thats the challenge. You make an array with the K first integers from the original array and try to put in other values if they are smaller..

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array and then return the sorted part of the array upto k.

```
public static int[] nrSmallest(int[] a, int k)  {
        if(k <1 || k>a.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("must be at least 1");
        Arrays.sort(a);        
        return Arrays.copyOf(a,k);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "pivoting" idea of quicksort, 
The pivot denotes the "rank" of that number in the array, so your end goal would be having a pivot at index "k", which will result in a subarray less than the Kth element, in other words first K smallest numbers (not exactly sorted).